# Show dates only after a specific date using calculated columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to show dates only after 31/12/2012. The Date column used here is a calculated column. I used the formula =[Created]>12/31/2012. But I need help with the syntax.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only "Yes/No" value to filter Created date then your formula is correct. You may have a problem if your regional settings are MM/DD/YYYY. In that case you should change the formula to `[Created]>31/12/2012`. Or the better way would be to change the condition to `[Created]>=01/01/2013`.
If you need the date, not "Yes/No" column, then this formula should work for you:

```
=IF([Created]>=1/1/2013,[Created],"TOO OLD")
```